# Encoding error on Linux, but not on Windows

Tags: python, linux, jdbc, encoding, character-encoding

I have to work with a very old post-relational database IBM U2 Universe, that works on UNIX AIX v5.1. There are some cyrillic strings that I need to read. I connect to DB from Python via JDBC (using JayDeBeApi library) using SQL command. There is script that generates .txt file with DB response:

```
import jaydebeapi

database = "UNIVERSE"
user = "USER"
password = "PASSWORD"

conn = jaydebeapi.connect("com.ibm.u2.jdbc.UniJDBCDriver",
                          f"""jdbc:ibm-u2://10.0.0.5:31438/USER;
                          databaseName={database}""",
                          {'user': user, 'password': password},
                          r'unijdbc.jar:asjava.zip')

curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute(f'SOME SQL COMMAND')
arr = curs.fetchall()

with open('output.txt', "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for element_i in arr:
        print(element_i)
        for element_j in element_i:
            if isinstance(element_j, str):
                f.write(element_j.encode('cp1251').decode('cp866', errors='ignore') + '\t')
            else:
                if element_j == None:
                    f.write('\t\t')
                else:    
                    f.write(str(element_j) + '\t\t')
        f.write('\n')

curs.close()
conn.close()
```

On Windows 10 everything works good and Python generates file with cyrillic strings, but when this script is running on Debian I have error:

```
('����� ᨭ���᪨� ��࠭����',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./universe_connect_25.06.2021.py", line 30, in <module>
    f.write(element_j.encode('cp1251').decode('cp866', errors='ignore') + '\t')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/encodings/cp1251.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: character maps to <undefined>
```

I've tried to experiment with string

```
f.write(element_j.encode('cp1251').decode('cp866', errors='ignore') + '\t')
```

with a different encodings. With some encodings, script returns an output file with symbols in unknown encoding, that unable to read and decode. More precisely, it looks very damaged:

```
я┐╜я┐╜ходя┐╜ я┐╜я┐╜ разрабя┐╜тки ценя┐╜я┐╜я┐╜тей я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜ывая┐╜я┐╜я┐╜  // in Linux
Отходы от разработки ценностей учитываемые                              // in Windows
```

I've tried to change system locale to C.UTF-8 and ru_RU.UTF-8, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Before any encode and decode, print the string content in hexadecimal.

Comment: You are using a "driver" to retrieve data. It may uses a different encoding. And I recommend you never to use `print` if you do not know that terminal capabilities.

Comment: After replacing my JDBC driver with another, newer one that I found on the internet, script stopped working. I've also tried to convert strings to hexadecimal with
`f.write(":".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in element_j) + '\t')`
But strings still looks damaged:
`fffd:fffd:5ba4:fffd:20:fffd:fffd:20:827:821:fffd:2aa8:20:696d:fffd:fffd:fffd:2969:20:fffd:fffd:fffd:b8a0:fffd:fffd:fffd`